# Storing offset/position of DOM element when all page resources have loaded

Tags: jquery, load

I have a DOM element that I am storing the offset position of. For example:

`$element.data('offset', $element.offset().top);`

However, because the page uses Web fonts and has images that have no explicit `width` or `height` attributes in the HTML, the page length actually increases as these items finish loading.

Therefore, if this code is run before all resources have loaded completely, the offset will be different. For example, `500` if the Web fonts are still loading, and `1000` if everything has loaded.

I've tried using the jQuery `load` function. This improves the situation, storing the offset only once the page has completely loaded around 70% of the time. However, I need 100% accuracy.

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google WebFont Loader, namely the `active()` callback. The loader supports font libraries other than Google, so you can load your own fonts:

https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader

Comment: Perfect. Almost there... I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/gG8DE/. This is firing the code when the Typekit fonts have loaded. However, I need to mix this is with `$(window).load()` somehow. The Typekit fonts need to have loaded as well as everything else...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `load` on `window` object which is fired when all the resources are loaded on the page, may be it will help you.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $element.data('offset', $element.offset().top);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this: "This improves the situation, storing the offset only once the page has completely loaded around 70% of the time. However, I need 100% accuracy."

Comment: The offset or position of a DOM element. However, this is changing as the page continues to load.

Comment: I mean why do you want to store the position? What will u do with that?

Comment: That is beside the point. I need the offset value when the page has finished loading.

Comment: You can get the offset on demand whenever you need by using the same line of code.

Comment: Yes, but I am moving the element after storing it's offset, so the offset will be changed. I am storing the offset to allow the element to return to its previous position later in the app.

Comment: Are you moving the element on page load? or later?